# Create a new column, leave first row in column blank?

Tags: r

My data.frame `Analysis` is structured as the following, where `X` and `Y` refers to the co-ordinates of a subject, `ID` over a period of `Time`

```
X <- c(10.32,10.97,11.27)
Y <- c(32.57,33.54,33.98)
Time <- c(1,2,1)
ID <- c("Rod", "Rod", "Greg")
```

I wish to know the distance each `ID` covers across `Time` or rows. My data.frame is 321300 obs. of 3 variables, so I am after an iteration across all rows in `Analysis`. I use the following to calculate distance:

```
out <- sapply(1:(nrow(Analysis)-1), function(i) {
  d <- dist(Analysis[i:(i+1),1:2])
})
```

I then wish to add `out` to `Analysis` using the code below:

```
Analysis$Distance <- out
```

I wish to leave the first row in `Analysis$Distance` blank (as there is NA distance) but am unsure how to 1. complete and 2. add into my original code?

Comment: I think the 'X' has one observation more or may be `,` instead of `.` and the `Greg` needs a closing `"`

Comment: Can you tidy up your question by showing the exact structure of your data frame?

Comment: Edits have been made, thank you!

Comment: Related: any question where a diff-type function returns a vector with (R-1) rows http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26079651/compute-time-delta-in-r-data-table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood the question correctly, we want to compute the distances travelled by each subject-id for each time period (and not across subject ids) and, therefore, the question is not about just inserting a NA at the front but also about fixing the code to compute the distances correctly.

```
library(dplyr)

Analysis <- data.frame(
      X = c(10.32,10.97,11.27),
      Y = c(32.57,33.54,33.98),
      Time = c(1,2,1),
      ID = c("Rod", "Rod", "Greg"))

Analysis %>% 
  arrange(ID,Time) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate( lagX = lag(X), lagY = lag(Y)) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(Distance = 
    dist( matrix( c(X,Y,lagX,lagY),nrow=2,byrow=TRUE) ) 
  ) %>%
  select(-lagX, -lagY)
```

This produces the following:

```
      X     Y Time   ID Distance
1 11.27 33.98    1 Greg       NA
2 10.32 32.57    1  Rod       NA
3 10.97 33.54    2  Rod 1.167647
```

In other words, Greg has not travelled at all. While Rod has moved 1.167647 from time 1 to time 2.

(I apologize if I misunderstood the question - I am very new here!)

Comment: You understood the question correctly and your answer worked perfectly - thank you! You also drew my attention to the use of %>% which I rarely use but will make future use of. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It's as simple as concatenating `c(NA, out)`

```
Analysis$Distance <- c(NA, out)
```

because your dataframe has R = 321300 rows, hence `out` will have (R-1) rows.
This is in general what we do with functions like `diff()` which return (R-1) rows.

(Faster than creating your new column as all-NAs: `Analysis$Distance <- NA` then computing each row's Distance individually)